# GXT - Grid doesn't reflect changes

Tags: gwt, gxt

Could you please take a look at the code below to check what is wrong with it. Problem is that no data appears in the grid when the data is loaded. All the classes are below (I only post the part of application which relates to failed functionality):

**ItemGrid (the class represents the grid which renders a data retrieved through feedService.loadItems(asyncCallback))**

```
public class ItemGrid extends LayoutContainer {

    public ItemGrid() {
        setLayout(new FitLayout());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);
        final List<ColumnConfig> columns = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
        columns.add(new ColumnConfig("title", "Title", 200));
        columns.add(new ColumnConfig("description", "Description", 200));

        final ColumnModel columnModel = new ColumnModel(columns);
        final FeedServiceAsync feedService = Registry.get(RSSReaderConstant.FEED_SERVICE);
        RpcProxy<List<Item>> proxy = new RpcProxy<List<Item>>(){
            @Override
            protected void load(Object o, AsyncCallback<List<Item>> asyncCallback) {
                feedService.loadItems(asyncCallback);
            }
        };
        ListLoader<ListLoadResult<Item>> loader = new BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<Item>>(proxy);
        ListStore<ModelData> itemStore = new ListStore<ModelData>(loader);

        List<ModelData> modelDataList = itemStore.getModels();
        for (ModelData model : modelDataList) {
            System.out.println("I got that point");
            Map<String, Object> modelMap = model.getProperties();
            Set<String> keys = modelMap.keySet();
            for (String key : keys) {
                System.out.println("Key is " + key);
            }
        }

        Grid<ModelData> grid = new Grid<ModelData>(itemStore, columnModel);
        grid.setBorders(true);
        grid.setAutoExpandColumn("description");
        loader.load();
        add(grid);
    }
}
```

**RssMainPanel (container where grid is located)**

```
public class RssMainPanel extends ContentPanel {

    public RssMainPanel(String label) {
        setHeadingText(label);
        setLayout(new FitLayout());
        add(new ItemGrid());
    }
}
```

**Item.class (class that represents the entity)**

```
public class Item extends BaseModel implements IsSerializable {

    private String cathegory;
    private String description;
    private String link;
    private String title;

    public String getCathegory() {
        return cathegory;
    }

    public void setCathegory(String cathegory) {
        this.cathegory = cathegory;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

I hope that this part of code is sufficient. I understand that it might be a simple question but I'm new in GWT/GXT and stuck in the problem. I would aapreciate any feedback.

Comment: Is there a reason for using GXT 2.x instead of 3.x? Have you inspected the DOM in your browser? This could help pointing down the problem. Either the data never reaches the client, or it might be a layout problem.

Comment: @Darek Kay The reason to use GXT 2.X is that it is used in the commercial project I have joint a while ago. Thank you for prompt reply. I found the solution which is described ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem (frankly I don't understand why it might be a problem). The issue is in the Item-entity. I implemented BeanModelTag (instead of extending BaseModel), pass BeanModelReader in `BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<Item>>(proxy, reader)` as parameter and it works out. But I still don't undestand why extending BaseModel fails data transfer.